# Auto refresh an another page when new data is added Laravel 5.8 Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.8

I've been searching and trying on how to refresh an another page or blade file when a data is updated. In my case, whenever I click the *Call Next* button in my call.blade.php, the data would update or change in my wintwo.blade.php.

ui for call.blade.php
[image: call ui]

ui for wintwo.blade.php
[image: window ui]

Controller Store Code

```
$call = Call::find($request->id);
$call->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$call->counter_id = Auth::user()->counter_id;
$call->called = 'YES';
$call->save();

return response()->json($call);
```

call.blade.php javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#update').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: 'updatecall',
        data:{
            '_token':$('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'id':$('input[name=call_id]').val(),
        },
        success:function(data){
            window.location.reload(); 
            setInterval(function() {
                $('#update').load('{{ action('DetailController@index') }}');
            }, 1000);
        },
    });
}); </script>
```

wintwo.blade.php javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {

            window.location.href = '/queue'; // "/queue" is the url route for wintwo.blade.php

        }, 2000);

    }
</script>
```

It doesn't work. I've search a lot and tried but nothing gonna work.

Comment: You can show us what you tried so we avoid trying the same things.

Comment: code blocks arrangement

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Web Socket services like **Pusher** 
https://pusher.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Socket Programming like Laravel WebSockets or Use node.js with socket.io package.
Socket.io with Node.js is easy to learn.
https://socket.io/get-started/chat

Comment: yes, use node.js to watch changes in database and if change found refresh a page with jquery, If you want to use laravel web socket than that may difficult.

Comment: I have one last question. Is it also possible to have text to speech in socket.io? For example when the number is update there is also a speech that announce a number together?

Comment: may be yes , Or use Google voice input APIs with Your project,

Comment: okay. right now I already read your link above. I've been searching how to integrate socket.io and laravel